# MySQL System Database Corrupt

Tags: mysql

A while ago, I accidentally deleted all of my MYSQL databases. Somehow, I got them all back in place in MySQL (from an old filesystem backup, I think).

However, it has never upgraded fully since then. I mean, apt-get installs the new SQL version, but the tables are never updated. For a couple years now, MySQL has run fine, but sometimes a reboot is needed after an "apt-get upgrade" attempt (which always errors out the MySQL post-install process) to kick it back into gear.

When I run "dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.7" I get the following output:

```
Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Checking if update is needed.
Checking server version.
Running queries to upgrade MySQL server.
mysql_upgrade: [ERROR] 1812: Tablespace is missing for table `mysql`.`plugin`.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 5
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
```

It's pretty obvious that the system table "plugin" is not in the database file... but how do I get it back? How do I re-create it? Since it is running fine without it, I mean, could I steal one from another server? Isn't something better than nothing?

I have dozens of databases with tons of data. I really don't want to jeopardize that...

I really don't know where to start... Please help.

Thanks!!

Comment: BTW - I get the *exact* same error when I try to query mysql.plugin using select *...

Comment: What harm would/could it do if I "DROP TABLESPACE mysql.plugin" and then recreate the table from a "create" script generated from another similar database?

Answer (score 2):

So, I got this to work. Not finished completely, but for each table that was "detached" I used the following command:

```
alter table [error_table] import tablespace;
```

A couple tables threw an error that

```
Error Code: 1808. Schema mismatch (Table has ROW_TYPE_COMPACT row format, .ibd file has ROW_TYPE_DYNAMIC row format.)
```

I have not resolved this yet. When I try to change the row format, the whole database crashes. I'll update this solution once I figure that out. Otherwise, if anyone has an suggestions, I welcome them!

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the [`mysqlcheck`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html) utility.

```
mysqlcheck mysql plugin
```

Comment: Get this:
$ mysqlcheck mysql plugin -p
Enter password:
mysql.plugin
Warning  : InnoDB: Tablespace is missing for table mysql/plugin.
Error    : Tablespace is missing for table `mysql`.`plugin`.
error    : Corrupt

Comment: Not much to be done there.  You can save a copy of the databases you created, blow away the `/var/lib/mysql/*` files/directories and recreate using [`mysql_install_db`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-install-db.html), then move your local databases back in place.  You should be suspicious of this advice.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* that is how I got into this mess. I had accidentally deleted the "mysql" database(/schema) (but not the other ones) and then recreated it and moved the other ones back in there. I'm thinking of doing a "backup" to generate .sql files for all databases, blow everything away, create a new instance, as you said, then re-import and set up users and permissions again. I *really* don't want to do this as I have multiple GBs of data (so time and space consuming), it is tedious, and I don't know what the side-effects will be...

Comment: Yeah ... innodb changes the calculus a little on that.  I know for sure that works with myisam ... not sure about other engines.